# Is it possible to define and refer to constants in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

Is it it possible in MediaWiki to define a constant and then include the constant in other pages?

E.g. could `MY_HELP_MESSAGE` be defined as `If you want help, contact help@somedomain…`
and `MY_HELP_MESSAGE` be called via e.g. `{{MY_HELP_MESSAGE}}` (as per https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Variable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use `vardefine`.

```
#vardefine

    {{#vardefine:variablename|specifiedvalue}}
```

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Variables

Comment: vardefine works within the same page.  How do you define constants that can be referred to by more than one page?